# Convert an array of objects to JsonArray in Swift3

Tags: json, swift, swift3

I have my DataModel as this and it has a function name toJSON which converts this object to string representation of JSON

```
ContactEntry: NSObject {
    var name: String!
    var phone: String?
    var email: String?

    func toJson() -> String {
    var dict : [String: AnyObject] = [:]
    dict["name"] = (self.name ??  "") as AnyObject
    dict["phone"] = (self.phone ?? "") as AnyObject
    dict["email"] = (self.email ?? "") as AnyObject


    guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: []) else{
        return "{}"
    }

    guard let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
        return "{}"
    }
    return jsonString
}
}
```

It works very fine until now as I am getting correct JSON representation for this object.

Now I have to convert an array of ContactEntry to JsonArray.

I am doing this way but I am getting very weird symbols in the result string. 
Let's say

```
var contacts = [ContactEntry]()
var contactsStr = [String]()
...
for contact in contacts{
    contactsStr.append(contact.toJson())
}

do{
    let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: contactsStr, options: [])

    let jsonString = try? String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

    print(jsonString)
}
```

I am getting the output like this

`[\n  \"{\\\"phone\\\":\\\"+XXXX\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"YYYY\\\",\\\"email\\\":\\\"\\\"},\",\n  \".........\n]`

Please help me to do it in a better and clean way

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you share the print of `contactsStr`?

Comment: Forget `prettyPrinted`, that causes most of the *weird* output

Comment: @Frankie
This is how contactStr looks
["{\"phone\":\"+xxx\",\"name\":\"yyy\",\"email\":\"\"}", "{\"phone\":\"+xxx\",\"name\":\"yy\",\"email\":\"\"}", "{\"phone\":\"xxx\",\"name\":\"yyy\",\"email\":\"\"}", "{\"phone\":\"+yyy\",\"name\":\"xxxx\",\"email\":\"\"}", "{\"phone\"...

Comment: @vadian
Is this the best way to convert to JSON?
I don't have much of an experience in Swift but I am sure JSON serialisation and deserialisation is very common in Swift. Just wanted to know right practice

Comment: @vadian

I am not sure if I am following right technique.

Comment: `JSONSerialization` is the recommended way

Comment: @vadian I have removed the 
JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted
and now my code looks liks
let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: contactsStr, options: [])

but still getting the same output. I have edited the question also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are double serializing your output.  That's why I asked for the contact string.

Try:

```
func toJson() -> [String: AnyObject] {
    var dict : [String: AnyObject] = [:]
    dict["name"] = (self.name ??  "") as AnyObject
    dict["phone"] = (self.phone ?? "") as AnyObject
    dict["email"] = (self.email ?? "") as AnyObject
    return dict
}
```

With:

```
var contactsStr = [[String: AnyObject]]()
```

And print out the serialization.  It should just be singly escaping quotes such as `\"name\"`.  Not `\\"name\\"`